# Selecting pandas dataframe column by row-specific list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

For each row in a dataframe, I'm trying to select the column, which is specified in a list. The list has the same length as the dataframe has rows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4,5], 
                   "b":[3,4,5,6,7], 
                   "c":[9,10,11,12,13]})
lst = ["a","a","c","b","a"]
```

The result would look like this:

```
[1,2,11,6,5]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just [`lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) would be fine:

```
df.lookup(df.index,lst)
```

---

```
#array([ 1,  2, 11,  6,  5], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 3):

`lookup` should be the way, but try something diff

```
df.stack().reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index,lst])).values
array([ 1,  2, 11,  6,  5])
```